# How can I get and control the hair strands number?

Tags: particles, hair

I was wondering if there is a way to get the hair strands number in the viewport?

What I really want is to limit the number of hair to an exact number, for exemple 100 000 hairs.
Then convert them to mesh.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Like to see a number of individual particle ... like vertices can do? Or you mean to control amount of hair visibility in viewport?

Comment: Thanks @vklidu for your answer!

I mean the visibility in viewport and the number if you export as a mesh in order to export.

Comment: Amount of visibility you can controll under Particles Properties > Viewport Visibility ... And about the export ...I don't think I understood. If no one is answering here, explain it deeper and add some screenshots with a mockup or reference to let us understand better ... Don't create another comment, edit your original question and place all important info there. Thanks.